# Comparing C# datetime with SQL server date column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am building a hotel booking system for my first year college project. I don't know much about SQL yet.
In the application, the user can choose which type of hotel room and which days they want to make their bookings. After getting "check_in" and "check_out" dates from the user , the application will go and look at "bookings" table in the database and compare the available rooms based on the inputs.

This is the schema for 'bookings' table

```sql
CREATE TABLE bookings(
    id        int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    room_id   INT,
    cus_id    VARCHAR(40),
    check_in  DATE,
    check_out DATE,
    
    CONSTRAINT FK_bookings_roomId FOREIGN KEY(room_id) REFERENCES rooms(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_bookings_cusId FOREIGN KEY(cus_id) REFERENCES customers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Data in the "booking" table looks like this

[image]

To check if there is any available rooms within the "check_in" and "check_out" values from the users, I wrote the following query

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    rooms 
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            room_id 
        FROM
            bookings
        WHERE (
            ( check_in BETWEEN @checkIn AND @checkOut ) 
            OR 
            ( check_out BETWEEN @checkIn AND @checkOut )
            OR
            (
                ( check_in < @checkIn )
                AND 
                ( check_out > @checkOut ) 
            )
       )
    )
```

...but the query returns zero rows.

- How can I compare `DateTime` value from C# to Date value in SQL?
- Does SQL automatically convert my C# `DateTime` object to SQL `DATETIME` data type if I insert into the column with `DATETIME` data type?

Comment: Unrelated tip: You need to add `NOT NULL` to your `CREATE TABLE` columns as by-default they'll be created as `NULL`able, which you don't want (all of your columns should be explicitly marked as `NOT NULL` unless you _absolutely_ know it needs to be `NULL`able).

Comment: Please show us some sample data, ideally as a SQLFiddle or DBFiddle.

Comment: @Dai I have added what the sample of data from  'booking' table. Could you please check it again ?

Comment: *"Does SQL automatically convert my C# DateTime object to SQL DATETIME data type if I insert into the column with DATETIME data type?"* - That really depends on how you're doing your insert. If you're using parameters and giving them a `DateTime` type then yes, if you're using string concatenation, then no. We'd need to see your `c#` code to give a definitive answer on this. As an aside I think you can simplify your date check to simply `check_in <= @checkOut AND check_out >= @check_in`

Comment: As an aside, your entire where clause could be simplified to `check_in < @checkOut AND check_out > @checkIn` - see [Using T-SQL to find events that overlap (or don't)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5854/using-tsql-to-find-events-that-overlap-or-dont-in-sql-server/).

Comment: The date value is collected from "DataTimePicker" control as a string. For inserting into database, I am using dataset with table adapters and defined a method to insert data into the database.

Comment: I can't see any issues with your T-SQL: [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a170e1036dc5715d2362fa9f1dd139bb), so this is potentially down to how you are calling it, so I think you'll need to post that to get to the bottom of the issue as to why no rows are being returned

Comment: @GarethD I added a few new bookings sample data with different date ranges and it finally works. Thank you :)

Comment: For what it is worth, it is always worth trying to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your questions (using something like db<>fiddle, or SQL Fiddle for your SQL questions). In many cases you'll find that in just creating the example you solve your own issue (as it seems you have in this case).

Comment: Yeah. I was so worked up about the query is returning empty table no matter how many times I changed the query statement.